# dynamic way of representation in spark Cassandra structtype

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra

I use something like this, to insert into a table in spark Cassandra. If you see all the columns are hard coded, is there a good way of handling it dynamically?

```
val logSchema = StructType(Array(StructField("tablename", StringType, true), StructField("filename", StringType, true), StructField("number_of_rows", StringType, true), StructField("loadtime", StringType, true), StructField("statusdetail", StringType, true)))
```

Comment: Please review your questions ! Most of them were answered and they haven't been accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always insert via `saveToCassandra` an RDD of `CassandraRow` Objects which don't have to have an explicit schema.

Something like

```
rdd : RDD[Map[String, Any]]
rdd.map( row => CassandraRow.fromMap(row).saveToCassandra )
```

http://datastax.github.io/spark-cassandra-connector/ApiDocs/1.6.0-M2/spark-cassandra-connector/#com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraRow

Comment: Yes, I could do that, but there is a problem with Spark Cassandra that I can't use more than 22 columns.

Comment: That has nothing to do with this, that's a Scala 2.10 limitaiton on case classes. You should be able to use as many columns as you like with `fromMap` or if you use scala 2.11

Comment: Yeah, but I have a limitation to use 2.10, I'm using azure-spark-scala-mesos

Comment: But you can still use a Cassandrarow object regardless of Scala version

Comment: Sure, thanks, will try, at the moment I'm handling it programmatic.